# Applying a Transformation Matrix to Entire Graphics Including Axes in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, matrix, transformation

I'm working with a Graphics object in Mathematica and I want to apply a transformation matrix to the entire object, including its axes.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
graphics=Graphics[{}, Axes -> True]
matrix={{1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}
TheNeededFunctionThatTransformsGraphicsByMatrix[graphics,matrix] (* Should output a rotated axes. *)
```

Is there such a function in Mathematica?

Comment: `ViewMatrix` https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/ViewMatrix.html.en

Comment: Or simply `Rotate[Graphics[{}, Axes -> True], \[Pi]/4]`.

Comment: Thanks! ViewMatrix seems to be a option that only can be applied to a Graphics3D object.

Comment: Do you need the output to be a `Graphics[...]` expression? Will it be OK to transform the `graphics` to an `Image[...]`?

Comment: @benjaminchanming: In 3D you can draw to the plane `z=0` as if in 2D and then you can use `ViewMatrix`.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `ImagePerspectiveTransformation:`**

... and the matrix from the docs:

```
g = Graphics[{Darker@Cyan, RegularPolygon[5]}
  , Axes -> True
  , AxesStyle -> Yellow
  , Background -> Black
  , PlotRange -> All
  , Frame -> True
  ]

matrix = {{1, 1/3, 0}, {1/3, 1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1}}
ImagePerspectiveTransformation[Rasterize@g, matrix]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Rotate[Graphics[{}, Axes -> True], π/4]
```

Comment: Rotate works! But is there a more general function that do any linear transformation represented by a matrix?